# Unable to locate credentials when trying to copy files from s3-bucket to my ec2-instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

Im trying to copy files from my s3-bucket to my ec2-instance. 
When i run this command inside my ec2-instance: `aws s3 cp s3://amazing-demobucket-1/file.txt ./file.txt` i get following error: `Unable to locate credentials`

But the aws configure files is in my `~/.aws` in my local machine. Do i need to configure inside ec2-instance too? Or is there another command i can run outside my ec2-instance to download files from s3-bucket into ec2-instance ?

Thank for help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your AWS credentials on your local machine can't be seen by the `awscli` program on your EC2 instance. If you want to run the S3 copy command on the EC2 instance, you have two options:

1) Run `aws configure` on the EC2 instance and define the credentials on that machine (not recommended)

or

2) Create an [IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html) with the required permissions to copy the files (for example, with the AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess policy) and [attach the role to your EC2 instance](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/assign-iam-role-ec2-instance/)

Answer (score 2):

It might be issue with order of precedence.
AWS check Keys first in environment variables and then ~/.aws path

Try running below command to check where its looking for keys

```
aws configure list
```

You can find more details about precedence on below link

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html#config-settings-and-precedence

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using AWS credentials inside EC2, you can try with Creating IAM roles and attach it to EC2.

Steps:

i) Create IAM role for EC2 with S3 access
ii) Attach the IAM role to EC2 instance

For more reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html

Hope it helps.